# Using group of columns as a unique key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `requests` on which the columns are `id`, `placeId`, `songId`, `userId`

`id` is the primary index of the table. Rest of the columns are only unsigned integers and no other unique key is defined.

I want `placeId` & `songId` pairs to be unique, i.e., if a row has `placeId` : 5 and `songId` : 12, no other rows can have the same combination.

I want this check to happen in SQL level, so that I can query like `insert into requests (...) values (...) on duplicate key do something else`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can create a UNIQUE index on multiple columns like this

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX placeSong
ON requests (placeId, songId)
```

Answer (score 5):

Another method is to add an unique constraint to the table :

```
ALTER TABLE requests ADD CONSTRAINT placeSong UNIQUE( placeId , songId );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl` (
    `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `field1` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `field2` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `Index 2` (`field1`, `field2`)
);
```